# How can I include a variable for my connection string in the default settings value in the settings constructor and get it later?

Tags: c#, connection-string

I need to make the path for my database using the Application.StartupPath.

In the property settings for my connection string I have the following:

```
Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="{Application.StartupPath}\SampleDatabase.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30
```

I tried the solution below with **string.Format**, but it did not work for a variable.

```
string dataSource = string.Format($"{System.Environment.CurrentDirectory}\\SampleDatabase.mdf");
```

How about the solution below? Is it a good approach?

```
if (subString == "StartupPath")
{
    string stupdir = Application.StartupPath;
}
```

SqlDataAdapter doesn't contain a DataSource as well. I cannot find a good solution.

How can I specify a relative path to a database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the older, non-interpolated placeholder with the string in the property settings:

> Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename="{0}\SampleDatabase.mdf";Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30

Then use `string.Format()` with that after loading it:

```
string dataSource = string.Format(Properties.Settings.ConnectionString, Application.StartupPath);
```

But, for what it's worth, the startup path is probably the **wrong place** for the database. If this program will be installed to the Program Files folder in Windows, normal users do have write access to this location, and haven't since at least Windows 2000 (more than 20 years). You should probably deploy the database to the `Application Data` folder instead.

Typically, my installer will deploy a template database to the application's startup folder that only contains the basic structure and metadata. Then every time the application itself starts up, it will check the Application Data folder for an existing database. If it doesn't find it, it will copy the deployed template db to the folder.